# How to get a notification that user permissions have changed?

Tags: ios6

I have an app that accesses the native address book. With iOS 6, when my app first attempts to access the AB, the user is prompted to allow or deny access; from that point, the user can only change this in the Privacy settings screen.

My app has to behave differently depending on whether or not the user has allowed AB access. **Is there any way for my app to receive a notification when the user changes this permission?** There is a method in the new API that I can call to determine whether the user has granted AB access or not, but I don't want to have to poll continuously in order to be aware of when this changes.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12668187/1575017), iOS "notifies" your app by your background task expiration handler. Not an NSNotification as I was assuming...bummer.

Comment: Thanks for the link - I'm seeing that exact same problem, where putting the app in the background, changing the privacy setting, and then bringing the app back up causes it to crash. Sucks hard, but at least I can clearly blame Apple for this.