# App crash when change permission AddressBook in Settings

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2

Swift (iOS 8 / iOS 9): App crash when I change permission AddressBook in Settings on real device

[image: Error when permission change in Settings]
[image: Code]
[image: Code]

Comment: please put here some code for fetch contact details

Comment: This is normal behavior. Please see other identical questions : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522574/toggling-privacy-settings-will-kill-the-app

Comment: @ilesh I`m not fetch contacts, I only get access to AddressBook. When app working I switch access to AddressBook in device Settings. When permission switched - app crash. Thats all.

Comment: @user3375798 In iOS7 (Objective-C) I don`t have this error

Comment: App also quits in iOS7. Note, though: if running the app on the device normally - NOT in Xcode debugging - the app will automatically be relaunched after the permissions have changed. The user won't see that a crash occurred (assuming, of course, that the app handles everything properly on restart).

Comment: @user3375798 Ok, I understood. Thank you.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your app is not crashing its just forced to restart by iOS with new privacy settings. So when you change the privacy policy, app will be killed if its attached to debugger else it will restart or relaunch.

Note :  If the user at some point changes the Address Book, Calendars, Reminders, Camera, or Photos permissions, iOS will `SIGKILL` the app. **(It's not crash it's default behaviour of iOS)**

Comment: Thanks. Problem closed.

Comment: do you have some links from apple stating the same?

Comment: When I used the simulator, my app "crashed"; however, when testing on an actual iPhone, the app simply restarted as the described by the accepted answer above.