# App crash after turning off on iCloud Settings

Tags: swift, core-data, ios9, icloud, icloud-drive

I have fully working Core Data/iCloud app. But the problem I am having is when I was testing/searching for bugs, I found this one that I can´t solve even don´t know  where to look at. It happens when I go to iCloud Settings and turn it off for my app. Then the app just crashes with this error: 'Thread 1: signal SIGKILL' and no log output. Can anyone help me with that?

Any code you need just ask me and I will post.

Comment: iOS kill it ,see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522574/toggling-privacy-settings-will-kill-the-app

Comment: @WilsonXJ So there´s no solution?

Comment: @WilsonXJ I am reading a blog post that I think can solve the problem which it seems to be when I set iCloud Setting of my app to off, the app shuts off the icloud store and since there´s no other one to turn back to, it crashes. And this blog post guides how to deal when swithcing off icloud, problem is I can´t translate what the post says into Swift code. Could you take a look at it? Go down the page to the Topic: 'iCloud On / Off Switch'  link: https://www.objc.io/issues/10-syncing-data/icloud-core-data/

Comment: i think it can't , it talk about how to Implementing a switch,maybe a switch in the app not about the settings

Comment: You think it can´t what? But the problem is just as I said Wilson, when I switch off iCloud in iCloud Setting for just my app, the app crashes because it has no persistent store to look at. That´s why I need a local one and the logic to check if iCloud is on/off and do the switching accordingly.

Comment: sorry about that ,I am not familiar with iCloud .