# Different controller showing up when back from Settings

Tags: ios, swift

For the new user I have several onboarding screens (all of them are in the same `OnboardViewController`). If user is successfully registered, I'd change the root controller of my app from `OnboardViewController` to `PreLoadViewController`:

```
let mcVC = PreLoadController()
appDelegateTemp.window?.rootViewController = mcVC
```

I'm using this controller to display progress of the content loading. After the content is loaded, I'm changing the root controller once again:

```
if let appDelegateTemp = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
        let mcVC = MainViewController()
        let navy = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mcVC)
        appDelegateTemp.window?.rootViewController = navy
}
```

It works, but I have a very strange bug. When I'm trying to change settings (like, `mic settings` or `notifications settings`) from the app, I have to go to iPhone settings:

```
if let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) {
     UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl)
}
```

But when I'm back I'm shown the `OnboardViewController` again as if appDelegate doesn't remember that current root controller is `mcVC` (or, rather, `UINavigationController` with embed `mcVC`).

So, why is that, and what is the right way to fix this?

Comment: When you change settings on Device Settings app, app would be terminated in some cases(like changing privacy setting as show in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522574/toggling-privacy-settings-will-kill-the-app). So It seems the app relaunching again..

Comment: use can try to store some  value lets say `currentViewController` in `UserDefaults` and check in `appDelegate` which controller to present

Comment: No, @Natarajan is right, it's just an inevitable crash after changing some settings, it just wasn't obvious to me from simulator.